# Searching byte encoded integers, is it faster to convert to int or match the bytes?

Tags: python, byte

I have a binary file containing integers at known positions. I want to seek a specific integer, or byte sequence. I got the idea converting to integer would be more efficient given the byte version's resemblance to a string.

Should I convert each byte sequence to an integer for comparisons or use bytes?

How does the size of the byte sequence comprising each int effect this, eg would using 3 bytes incur an overhead of masking off the odd byte?

Comment: You're more likely to get performance improvements by choosing different tools for the actual searching process - for example, using Numpy stuff to compare two sequences (as your test appears to do), or using byte regexes (if you supply a pattern in a `bytes` object to the standard library `re` module, it can be used on source data that is also `bytes`).

Comment: (1) I wonder why you think I am using numpy stuff? True I am using pandas at points but I am reading binary data from a file with fixed row lengths here. I do not see a better way than plain python. (2) Do you have a link / example for `bytes` patterns to `re`?

Comment: 1) I don't think you are. I think it's possible that you *should*. It depends on exactly how your searching works. 2) it's functionally the same as doing it with strings; I don't really know how an example helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To answer I devised a small script. The slowest part is generating the randoms.

```
import random
import time

endianness = "big"
bytes_given_to_int = 3

def some_nums(top_end: int):
    return [x + random.randint(0, 42) for x in range(top_end)]

top_end = 9_999_999

bs = [x.to_bytes(bytes_given_to_int, endianness) for x in some_nums(top_end)]
bs2 = [x.to_bytes(bytes_given_to_int, endianness) for x in some_nums(top_end)]
cs = some_nums(top_end)
cs2 = some_nums(top_end)

iicmps=[]
bbcmps=[]
bicmps=[]
ibcmps=[]

for i in range(10):
    t0 = time.time()
    rs1 = [1 for i in range(top_end) if bs[i] == bs2[i]]
    # Each sum should be roughly equal. Using it here helps instruct the interpreter/compiler
    # not to optimise away the arbitrary task we give it.
    print(sum(rs1))
    bbcmps.append((time.time() - t0))
    t0 = time.time()
    rs2 = [1 for i in range(top_end) if cs[i] == cs2[i]]
    print(sum(rs2))
    iicmps.append((time.time() - t0))
    t0 = time.time()
    rs3 = [1 for i in range(top_end) if int.from_bytes(bs[i], endianness) == cs[i]]
    print(sum(rs3))
    bicmps.append((time.time() - t0))
    t0 = time.time()
    rs4 = [1 for i in range(top_end) if cs[i].to_bytes(bytes_given_to_int, endianness) == bs[i]]
    print(sum(rs4))
    ibcmps.append((time.time() - t0))


print("Comparing byte sequences took {:.2f}s".format(sum(bbcmps) / len(bbcmps)))
print("Comparing ints took {:.2f}s".format(sum(iicmps) / len(iicmps)))
print("Comparing byte sequences (converted to ints) to ints took {:.2f}s".format(sum(bicmps) / len(bicmps)))
print("Comparing ints (converted to byte sequences) to byte sequences took {:.2f}s".format(sum(ibcmps) / len(ibcmps)))
```

> Comparing byte sequences took 1.54s
>
> Comparing ints took 1.50s
>
> Comparing byte sequences (converted to ints) to ints took 3.53s
>
> Comparing ints (converted to byte sequences) to byte sequences took 3.52s

Ok, this shows byte sequences to be first class objects, as we might deduce from even strings being a thin veneer on lists.

What happens with other word lengths? Let's try 4.

> Comparing byte sequences took 1.31s
>
> Comparing ints took 5.89s
>
> Comparing byte sequences (converted to ints) to ints took 3.29s
>
> Comparing ints (converted to byte sequences) to byte sequences took 3.20s

I guess the variables in this script are useful! byte sequences FTW!

Comment: You should use the `timeit` standard library module to do performance testing, rather than rolling it yourself.

Comment: I don't get to do a lot of optimisations professionally, thanks for the suggestion